# Geocoder near method with model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to get the near method from geocoder gem working with a model that is associated with another model. I have 2 models restaurants and menus, menus belongs to restaurants. I have a form with a search method in each model, the near method works with my restaurants model

```
 def self.search_for(params)
      restaurants = Restaurant.where(category_id: params[:category].to_i)
      restaurants = restaurants.near(params[:location],2) if params[:location].present?
      restaurants
end
```

I'm searching for a restaurant near the user that sells a dish the user has entered, however the code gives a no method error (`undefined method 'restaurants'`)

```
def self.search_for_menus(params)

    menus=Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%") if params[:dish].present?
    menus= menus.restaurants.near(params[:location],2) if params[:location].present?
   menus
  end
```

In my console I am able to do `m=Menu.find(11)` then `m.restaurant` which returns that restaurant object and can further do `m.restaurant.address` which gives the address for geocoder near method to work, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Edited Code:

```
 def self.search_for_menus(params)

    menus=Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%") if params[:dish].present?
    rest_menu = []
    menus.each do |menu|
    rest_menu << menu.restaurant.nearbys(params[:location],2) if params[:location].present?

    end


   rest_menu

  end
```

Comment: Since you have undefined method restaurants and you're calling that on menus, that means menus is undefined at the time the code is running. Maybe your "if" conditional returns false on the line where you define menus. This would be more easily solved using a debugger like byebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, it requires a join on the parent model and a reverse geocode

```
 reverse_geocoded_by "restaurants.latitude", "restaurants.longitude"

  def self.search_for_menus(params)

    menus=Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%") if params[:dish].present?
    menus= menus.joins(:restaurant).near(params[:location],2)

   menus

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If We looked up to Method self.search_for_menus(params) Which is help to search menus

Inside the Method you are using the

```
Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%")
```

You are using the where query which result to gives you the array of record and you are trying to find the associated restaurant according to menus

Its not able to find on multiple records Association are only work in single record.

If You ensure the query will always return the 1 result then you can try this

```
menus=Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%").first if params[:dish].present?
menus= menus.restaurants.near(params[:location],2) if params[:location].present?
```

If records in "menus" are multiple then try to do looping in each record of menus

like:

```
rest_menus  = []
menus.each do |menu|
restaurant_location = menu.restaurants.near(params[:location],2) if   params[:location].present?
rest_menus << restaurant_location if restaurant_location.present?
end
```

Comment: Ok I understand,  but in the first instance with just restuarants.where category_id clause, didn't that also return an array? The near method worked in that case and I got a list of restaurants near a location.So I figured in theory the menu.restaurant would work, I tried your method and am now getting a "undefined method `merge!' for 2:Fixnum" error

Comment: Yeah Its working because In the case of first you are not calling a association you are calling directly a near method with associated bunch of data in array of restraurant. Near method can be able to call with bunch of data in array but you cant call a association with bunch of array in single calling. A error of undefined method merge! for diffrent method its not raises due to above code .shared code will look into this

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated the code with your solution in the original post above, this code now gives me the "undefined method `merge!' for 2:Fixnum" error, thanks for taking a look

Comment: Try above updated code i think its will gives you perfect result

Comment: Thanks for your help but still got the same error, I managed to find a solution